# Behaviour of call_once while exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11

If I call a function with `call_once` and if it throws exception before completing execution, what will be the value of `once_flag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`once_flag` state is not modified so the next call to `call_once` with the same `once_flag` will invoke the callable.

From [*[thread.once.callonce]*/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.once.callonce#2) (emphasis added)

> *Effects*: An execution of `call_­once` that does not call its `func` is a *passive* execution. An execution of `call_­once` that calls its `func` is an *active* execution. An active execution shall call `INVOKE(​std​::​forward<Callable>(func), std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`. **If such a call to `func` throws an exception the execution is *exceptional*, otherwise it is *returning*.** An exceptional execution shall propagate the exception to the caller of `call_­once`. **Among all executions of `call_­once` for any given `once_­flag`: at most one shall be a returning execution**; if there is a returning execution, it shall be the last active execution; and there are passive executions only if there is a returning execution.